# Remover valor de uma variável POST para não duplicar inserção

Tags: php, ajax, post

Estou com um problema no meu site, quando eu clico em salvar dentro de um modal, ele envia os dados via Ajax e faz a inserção no banco, ao realizar esses passos, eu chamo uma função javascript para atualizar a pagina `window.location.reload();` porém quando atualiza a página, está inserindo duas vezes no banco, os dados POST está reenvindo e entrando no if de inserção.

Existe alguma maneira de limpar essas variaveis para que não entre dentro do if para inserção ao atualizar a pagina ? Ja tentei usar o `unset` mas não tive sucesso.

Usei o window.location.href e também não objetive sucesso.

Meu codigo abaixo:

```
if(isset($_POST['act2'])) $act2 = $_POST['act2'];

if(isset($act2)){

        ...//Aqui faz o processo de inserção no banco
}
```

Esse $act2 está vindo através do AJAX, como ao bloquear perder os dados o $act2, sem que ele venha como POST novamente, ou como atualizar a pagina sem que ele repita a inserção pois os dados POST são enviados novamente ao atualizar.

Comment: Tente usar o php pra redirecionar, substituindo o `window.location.reload();` por `header('Location:mesmapagina.php');
die();` Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4870934/4734177 (existem outras possíveis soluções na pergunta linkada)

Comment: Só uma dúvida... Se você está utilizando ajax por qual motivo está querendo atualizar a página após a requisição? Você está fazendo alguma ação diferente ao comportamento padrão do `form`? Segue uma solução que encontrei: https://www.kodementor.com/prevent-duplicate-form-submission-on-refresh-in-php/

Comment: A ideia de requisições assíncronas é justamente evitar o recarregamento ta página por completo, mas somente em áreas específicas

Comment: Quando eu clico em fechar a aba do modal, eu estou chamando uma função javascript para atualizar a pagina, quando eu atualizo, o formulário refaz o envio... O metodo para inserir está em Ajax mas para listar o conteudo da minha tabela, não está em ajax, por isso que atualizo ao fechar o modal.

Comment: Tem que mostrar o Ajax e o formulário. Só com essas informações é difícil dizer alguma coisa.